# MySQL explain shows "Using Temporary"

Tags: mysql, optimization, key, explain

I am trying to optimize my mySQL query and I am coming across a strange problem.

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT `survey_visit`.`id` 
FROM `survey_visit` 
LEFT JOIN `campaign` ON `survey_visit`.`campaign_alphanumeric` = `campaign`.`alphanumeric` 
ORDER BY `visit_date` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

The EXPLAIN shows that I read 5 rows in the survey_visit table. However, if I do a second join as follows:

```
SELECT `survey_visit`.`id` 
FROM `survey_visit` 
LEFT JOIN `campaign` ON `survey_visit`.`campaign_alphanumeric` = `campaign`.`alphanumeric` 
LEFT JOIN `client` ON `campaign`.`fk_clientID` = `client`.`id`
ORDER BY `visit_date` DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

then it uses a temporary table, uses filesort and reads through all records. Note that the problem is very specific to joining the "client" table. I have tried joining other tables and it all works fine. I have checked the indexes and all seems to be well.

Any advice is most appreciated.

Here is the EXPLAIN on the second query:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [select_type] => SIMPLE
        [table] => survey_visit
        [type] => ALL
        [possible_keys] => 
        [key] => 
        [key_len] => 
        [ref] => 
        [rows] => 1564
        [Extra] => Using temporary; Using filesort
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [select_type] => SIMPLE
        [table] => campaign
        [type] => eq_ref
        [possible_keys] => alphanumeric
        [key] => alphanumeric
        [key_len] => 12
        [ref] => bpharma.survey_visit.campaign_alphanumeric
        [rows] => 1
        [Extra] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [select_type] => SIMPLE
        [table] => client
        [type] => index
        [possible_keys] => PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE
        [key] => PRIMARY
        [key_len] => 4
        [ref] => 
        [rows] => 2
        [Extra] => Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
    )
```

EDIT:
Here is the EXPLAIN for query 1. Thanks

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [select_type] => SIMPLE
        [table] => survey_visit
        [type] => index
        [possible_keys] => 
        [key] => survey_visit_visit_date_index
        [key_len] => 6
        [ref] => 
        [rows] => 5
        [Extra] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [select_type] => SIMPLE
        [table] => campaign
        [type] => eq_ref
        [possible_keys] => campaign_alphanumeric_uindex
        [key] => campaign_alphanumeric_uindex
        [key_len] => 12
        [ref] => bpharma.survey_visit.campaign_alphanumeric
        [rows] => 1
        [Extra] => Using index
    )
```

Comment: I have just tested "select campaign.* from campaign left join client..." and it uses a temporary table. I must have a problem with a campaign index?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an index on `visit_date`? If yes, please add the explain output for your first query. If not, add it. Also: is `campaign`.`alphanumeric` unique? If so, add that as a unique index.

Comment: zerkms: I am a newbie to optimization and I am using this query as my learning curve. Basically, if i don't include the client table, the query only hits a few rows and survey_visit uses the indexes. But if I join with client then suddenly it won't use the survey_visit indexes and creates a temporary table. My understanding is that a temporary table is a very bad thing. I want to understand what is going on..

Comment: thanks solarflare. EXPLAIN for query 1 added.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/16/how-much-overhead-is-caused-by-on-disk-temporary-tables/

Comment: thanks.. if I understand correctly, this isn't a bad thing?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables; we need to see the indexes, datatypes, etc.